# how to get embed image from current outlook email with c#?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am developing outlook 2010 add-in with c#.net in visual studio 2010.

I want to get embed image from current email ( not attached) in to my form region.

how to get embed image from outlook email ?

I tried to find out from google but all of them shows how to embed image in email.
but i want to get embedded image from outlook email.

can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`.  Here is a huge list of items within the [Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.aspx). You may have to treat it like an attachment; save it to another folder.  Then recursively pull the data from there.

```
private void ThisApplication_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.NewMail += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
        .ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailEventHandler(ThisApplication_NewMail);
}

private void ThisApplication_NewMail()
{
    Outlook.MAPIFolder inBox = this.ActiveExplorer()
        .Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook
        .OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    Outlook.Items inBoxItems = inBox.Items;
    Outlook.MailItem newEmail = null;
    inBoxItems = inBoxItems.Restrict("[Unread] = true");
    try
    {
        foreach (object collectionItem in inBoxItems)
        {
            newEmail = collectionItem as Outlook.MailItem;
            if (newEmail != null)
            {
                if (newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= newEmail
                       .Attachments.Count; i++)
                    {
                        newEmail.Attachments[i].SaveAsFile
                            (@"C:\TestFileSave\" +
                            newEmail.Attachments[i].FileName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string errorInfo = (string)ex.Message
            .Substring(0, 11);
        if (errorInfo == "Cannot save")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Create Folder C:\TestFileSave");
        }
    }
}
```

That will save the embed or attached items to a directory of your choice; then you can simply manipulate those attached items however you choose.  Hopefully that at least points you in the write direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot Greg. your code has solved my problem. Thanks a lott.